# Query to find the difference between successive rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-table

As I am new to MySQL, this question may be silly. How can I find the difference between successive rows?
Example:
A table (tableName='Abc') contains a single row as follows,

```
|DATA|
|10  |
|20  |
|30  |
|40  |
|50  |
```

Here I want get the output as,

```
|Dif|
|10 |
|10 |
|10 |
|10 |
```

How to find the difference like this without any index (primary or Auto_increment)?

Comment: That's a column, not a row, and it's only coincidentally ordered. Unless you use an ORDER BY clause in a SQL statement, MySQL can return the data in any order.

Answer (score 9):

A self-join is one way to compare consecutive rows:

```
SELECT
    MIN(T2.DATA - T1.DATA) AS Dif
FROM
    Abc T1 INNER JOIN Abc T2 on T1.DATA < T2.DATA
ORDER BY
    T1.DATA
```

Comment: `on T1.DATA < T2.DATA` wouldn't cause all rows below to produce a x*y rows ? I mean it wouldn't join 50&10,50&20,.. etc ?

Comment: @prajeeshkumar The join would be triangular `(x*x+x)/2` if it weren't for `MIN()`, which ensures the rows match 1:1, except the last row, which doesn't match anything. The result is `x-1` rows.

Comment: This seems to work only for monotonically increasing datasets, no? Did I miss something? When I run it, I get either a singleton (when there are no differences between values) or incorrect time differencing (when the dataset is non-monotonic).

Comment: Using group by instead of order by gives me the results I'm seeking

Answer (score 7):

Use user-defined variables:

```
SET @prevValue:=0;
SELECT value-@prevValue AS diff,@prevValue:=value FROM t;
```

You'll have to discard the first row for your case.

If the table contains both `value` and `diff` fields, you can set the `diff` field with:

```
SET @prevValue:=0;
UPDATE t SET diff=IF((@d:=value-@prevValue) AND (@prevValue:=value),@d,@d);
```

Using the `IF` is the only way I could find to **both** set `diff` **and** update the `@prevValue` variable.

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to do this outside of the DB by keeping track of the previous row. Here's some code (hopefully my php is not too rusty):

```
<?php

$prevNum = 0;

$db = mysql_connect(...); // fill in connection string

mysql_select_db("my_db", $db);

$result = mysql_query("select DATA from Abc order by DATA");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $diff = $row[0] - $prevNum;

    echo "$diff\n";

    $prevNum = $row[0];

}

?>
```

If you need to do it within the db for some reason then it would probably be best to create a stored procedure which will basically do the same thing: instantiate a variable with value 0, report the difference for each row and that variable, then set the variable to the row value.

Edited to add an order by clause as noted by John Pick